# subset to drop some value in column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and one column has p value and I want to remove pvalue =NaN

```
sample  PValue
a        0.5
b        NaN
c        NaN
```

I want to select a data which doest'n have PValue =NaN

Is subset commmand can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways you could do it. Try:

```
df <- df[!is.nan(PValue),]
```

also look into `?is.na` or `?na.omit`. The latter will also omit rows with NA values in other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `df` is your data frame

```
> na.omit(df)
  sample PValue
1      a    0.5
```

See `?na.omit` for further details.